# Uva 10364 Tell if it is possible to use sticks of varying lengths to make a square

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I have been stuck on [this uva problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/103/10364.html) from a long time now.

Abridged problem statement : Given a set of sticks of various lengths, is it possible to join them end-to-end to form a square? There are a maximum of 20 sticks and each stick has a length less than 10000.

There are different solutions possible for this problem. One of them is a backtracking solution explained [here](http://amrfeldfrawy.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/uva-10364-square/). But there exists other dynamic programming solutions explained [here](http://f0rth3r3c0rd.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/uva-10364-square/), [here](http://ajmarin.alwaysdata.net/codes/problems/989/) and [here](http://kaikaiw321.blogspot.in/2013/09/uva-10364.html) with a better running time. But I can't understand what approach they are using. Please help me understand the dp algorithm.

Comment: Do you expect us to search ourselves for the description of the dynamic programming solutions? Show us some code.

Comment: I dont understand "how are there too many possible answers or good answers will be too long for this format". Why 2 close votes?

Comment: For it to be a square, the square has to have the same length on each side, which means that you sum the squares up, divide by 4, then you find the target sum. Your problem is now to find 4 distinct sets of sticks that sum to that length. The reason for the close votes is your request for "some possible". You're thus not asking for *an* answer, you're asking for *many* answers, and thus makes this question illfit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: And to be honest, if you've already found some dynamic solutions, and then ask people to suggest dynamic solutions, **what exactly is your question?** Why not ask why one of those solutions work instead of this? Here's some suggestions to dynamic solutions: http://f0rth3r3c0rd.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/uva-10364-square/, http://ajmarin.alwaysdata.net/codes/problems/989/, and http://kaikaiw321.blogspot.in/2013/09/uva-10364.html

Comment: Yes I understand this but the 4 sets of sticks that I make must be disjoint and I must use all the sticks. So I think this problem is definitely harder than a knapsack problem and not that trivial.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I wanted to post this as a new question altogether rather than just give a solution and ask to explain it.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem here is that you've asked this: I have this problem. I have found some solutions here, here, and here. Please suggest some solutions. Again, **what is the question here?**

Comment: I believe the answer I have given does correspond to the question as it is currently stated ("Please help me understand the dp algorithm.") Sure, there can be several DP algorithms, not "the algorithm", but the general idea of dynamic programming over subsets remains the same, and I tried my best to illustrate it by the answer. Similarly, there can be several possible fixes for one's broken code, but the idea of what's wrong remains the same, and "fix my code" questions are OK on the site.

Comment: I'd also like to note that there is a proposal on Area51 in commitment stage dedicated to Competitive Programming: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52595/competitive-programming. I believe the question in its current form (what's the idea behind the DP in this problem) would fit there, maybe after some rewording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not familiar with dynamic programming over subsets, I suggest you read about it first. [This link](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/337) can help, but there may be better tutorials out there.

Back to the given problem, since M is no more than 20, the following 2<sup>M</sup>×M approach will probably work.

For each of the 2<sup>M</sup> subsets of the given sticks, we know the total length of the sticks in that subset. We also know the total length of all the given sticks and thus the length of the square side. We construct the square by laying sticks on its sides. Let us fix the order in which we construct our square: we start at the upper left corner and move along the square border in clockwise direction, laying sticks on the way and leaving no gaps. So, first we fully construct the upper side (from left to right), then the right side (top-down), then the lower one (right-to-left) and finally the left one (bottom-up). Whenever the distance to the next square corner in our traversal is L, we can't lay a stick of length greater than L; at least not until we reach that corner using other sticks. Now, the question is: can we order the sticks in such a way that the square can be constructed by our procedure?

There are M! different orders in which we can try to lay the sticks. But, if we lay sticks one-by-one, when choosing the next stick, all that we are concerned with is the *set* of sticks already laid, not their particular *order*. This observation leads us to considering only 2<sup>M</sup> subsets which is way smaller than M! orders.

Next we define subproblems of the problem defined before. For each subset of sticks, the question is: can we order the sticks in such a way that all of them can be laid sequentially by the rules of the above procedure? In other words, can we construct a "valid prefix" of the square traversal, as it is defined above?

We will say a subset of sticks is *good* if the answer to the above question is "yes", and *bad* otherwise. Sure, the empty subset is *good*. In the end, we are interested in whether the whole given set of sticks is also *good*. To find that out, we can process the subsets in natural order (for M=3, that would be 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 where 1s correspond to sticks in the subset). For each new non-empty subset S, it is *good* if and only if some of its "immediate subsets" T (S without exactly one element - say a stick of length X) is *good*, and T can be extended by that stick of length X according to the rules of our construction procedure (that is, laying a stick of length X, we won't have to bend it around some corner).

What's left is implementation details. For each subset, either store or calculate the total length of the sticks in it and find the distance to the next corner L. If this subset is good, it can be extended only by sticks having two properties: (1) length no more than L and (2) not already in the subset.